# Human pose estimation - efficient linking of body parts

Tags: image-processing

**Problem's description:** 
I am working at a project whose goal is to identify people's body parts in images (torso, head, left and right arms etc). The approach is based on finding parts of the human body (hypothesis) and then searching for the best pose configuration (= all the parts that really form a human body). The ideea is described better at this link http://www.di.ens.fr/willow/events/cvml2010/materials/INRIA_summer_school_2010_Andrew_human_pose.pdf.

The hypothesis are obtained after running a detection algorithm (here I am using a classifier from machine learning field) for each body part separately. So, the type of each hypothesis is known. Also, each hypothesis has a location (x and y coordinates in the image) and an orientation.

To determine the cost of linking two parts together, one can consider that each hypothesis of type head can be linked with each hypothesis of type torso (for example). But, a head hypothesis which is in the top right location of the image can not be linked (from a human point of view) with a torso hypothesis which is in the bottom left location of the image. I am trying to avoid these kinds of links based on the last statement and also due to the execution time.

**Question:** I am planing to reduce the searching space by considering a distance to the farthest hypothesis which can be a linking candidate. Which is the fastest way of solving this searching problem?

Comment: Are you looking for the name of an algorithm which you can research further?

Comment: Not to answer your specific question, but just giving you a link to a related project that it may be useful (or not) to you :-) https://github.com/joaquimrocha/Skeltrack

Comment: Yes, I need an algorithm or any other approach which performs better than the one of considering all the possible links between 2 hypothesis of different type.

Comment: @Nelson: thank you for your suggestion, but the input images in my case are simple RGB images.

Answer (score 2):

For similar problems I have resorted to spliting the source images into 16 (or more, depending on the relative size of the parts you're trying to link) smaller images, doing the detection and linking step in each of these seperatly, and an extra step where you will do only a link step for each subimage, and it's (possibly 8) neighbours.

In this case you will never even try to link one part in the upper left corner with the lower right one, and as an added bonus the first part of your problem is now extremely parallel.

Update:
You could do a edge detection on the image first, and never cut the image in 2 when that would mean cutting an edge in two. recursively doing this would allow you to get a lot of small images with body parts on them you can then process separately.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I give you +1 for the ideea of running the detection algorithm in parallel. But, I am not sure about the linking approach that you proposed. As I mentioned in the last comment for @sansuiso's answer, I am trying to implement this by using an octree.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of discrete assignment problem can be solved using the [Hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).

In the computation of the cost (= distance) matrix, you can set the entry to some infinite or very high value when the distance is grater than a predefined threshold,
This will prevent the algorithm from assigning a head to a torso which is too far away.

This last technique is also called **gating** in tracking lectures.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but, as far as I understand, in this way I should compare each torso hypothesis with each head hypothesis (for example) to obtain the cost matrix. But, my intention was to avoid the unnecessary computations (= trying to link two parts that are too far away from each other).

Comment: The Hungarian algorithm is an efficient algorithm to solve this problem. It is really worth trying it. You can check its algorithmic complexity on the link I provided.

Comment: I was looking over the link you indicated. The complexity is O(n^3). But, I think that this linking process can be done with a better complexity. Now, I am trying to implement it by using an octree. If n is the number of torso hypothesis and m is the number of head hypothesis, then the complexity of building the tree is O(nlog(n)) and for finding the nearets neighbours for all heads is >= O(mlog(n)) (best case = O(mlog(n)).